Pyarrow installation failed on Alpine images
I am trying to install pyarrow on alpine image using docker.
Pyarrow needs Arrow C++ libraries preinstalled which I have installed first
Below is the dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-alpine

 RUN apk add --no-cache \
    build-base \
    cmake \
    boost-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    curl \
    bash \
    git \
    openssl-dev \
    py3-pip \
    py3-numpy \
    py3-wheel

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    apache-arrow-dev \
    py3-setuptools 

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    python3-dev \
    musl-dev \
    linux-headers

RUN git clone https://github.com/apache/arrow.git /arrow \
    && cd /arrow/cpp \
    && mkdir build \
    && cd build \
    && cmake .. \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install

ENV CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local/lib/cmake/Arrow"

RUN python3 -m ensurepip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install pyarrow

However, the installation fails with the following error messages:
error: 'Wrap' is not a member of 'arrow::py::{anonymous}::WrapBytes<arrow::Decimal32Type>'
Steps Taken:
Upgraded Pip: Ensured that pip is at least version 19.0.
Attempted Prebuilt Binaries: Tried installing pyarrow without the --no-binary flag.
Specified Version: Attempted to install a specific version of pyarrow.
Checked Dependencies: Ensured that all necessary system dependencies are installed.
What can I do to successfully install pyarrow in my Docker container? Are there specific dependencies or configurations I should consider?
Thank you!

For Python in particular, the default Debian-based images can frequently use precompiled "wheel" format packages, and it is much faster and easier to build an image if you don't use an Alpine base.  For PyArrow 17.0.0, it looks like there are wheel files for Python 3.8 through 3.12, for 64-bit x86 and ARM systems, but they won't work with Alpine.  If you use a Debian-based image, do you need the C toolchain or extra library dependency?

It may be confusing for your system to have apache-arrow-dev and then a clone of the apache repo, as well as pyarrow installed with pip. My limited understanding is that if you are going to install pyarrow from source using pip, you don't need the repo cloned if you already have apache-arrow-dev. Also I think apache-arrow-dev and pyarrow are both on version 17.0.0, but the git clone is using master, which includes changes for the upcoming version 18.0.0. So you should try to clone the tag of version 17.0.0.

@DavidMaze Thabk you for reply .. but I have restrictions and need to use Alpine images.

@0x26res Thank you very much for your answer. it did solve my issue.

As per suggestion above below command worked for me :
RUN git clone --no-checkout https://github.com/apache/arrow.git /arrow \
&& cd /arrow \
&& git checkout tags/apache-arrow-17.0.0 \
&& cd cpp \
&& mkdir build \
&& cd build \
&& cmake -DARROW_CSV=ON -DARROW_JSON=ON -DARROW_FILESYSTEM=ON .. \
&& make -j$(nproc) \
&& make install

